# MySql on duplicate return error

Tags: mysql, sql

While firing INSERT query, is it possible to return error (or anything else to indicate) if one of the values i wish to insert, already exist in the table?

```
INSERT INTO `private_customers`(`first_name`, `phone_number`) 
VALUES ('the_first_name','1122334455') 
// if the phone number is already exist in the table then don't insert nothing and return indication that it is already exist
```

Comment: Add a `unique` constraint on `(phone_number)`?

Comment: If you don't want to create `UNIQUE` constraint, just do 1. `SELECT` to check wether the phone number already exists, 2. your `INSERT`, 3. profit.

Comment: But can't two private customers share the same number? (e.g. a couple living together.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add unique indexes:

```
create unique index idx_private_custoemrs_fn on private_customers(first_name);
create unique index idx_private_custoemrs_pn on private_customers(phone_number);
```

If you want the *pair* of values to be unique, then create the index on the *pair*:

```
create unique index idx_private_custoemrs_fn_pn on private_customers(first_name, phone_number);
```

(And don't include the other two indexes.)

Comment: Now i get the duplication error after setting up a unique constraint and trying to insert the same value again, but how can i tell if the error is about the duplication? is there a special error number or a special value returned in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a unique constraint to achieve it.